# How to get response to POST request from flask to JavaScript ajax?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I have made a post request from JavaScript to my Flask python code through ajax, but I cannot find a way to return the data in a way that will allow me to get is again through the JavaScript. What I'm trying to do is send data to the Flask server, and return other data back to the JavaScript.

I have tried to use a `success: function` but it doesn't seem to work and seen as a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

The relevant part of the JavaScript code:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/login",
            data: JSON.stringify(login_info),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json'
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

The `data` im trying to get is the `results` from the code below V

The Flask(python) code:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_info = request.get_json()
        print(user_info)

        results = {'processed': 'true'}
        return jsonify(results)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

Comment: you're missing a comma after `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax options object in JS

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.